# Angularjs variable get http in controller invisible

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is the variable that is not visible in the controller, visible only in html?

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "get",
        url: "xxxxxx.php"
    })
    .success(function(gl){
        $scope.users = gl;    
    });

    // Initial  data
    var e =  request.users;
    $scope.chartData = [
        ['Coo',e],
    ];
});
```

Comment: Clarify your question, what are you trying to do?

Comment: insert variables from php to the controller

Comment: Are you `echo`ing some data in your view ?

Comment: How do you `insert variables from php` ? What its mean `**var e =  request.users;**` ?

Comment: He wants to insert  $scope.users = gl    in  $scope.chartData = [
        ['Coo',e],

Answer (score 0):

Construct `$scope.chartData` inside `$http.success` like

```
var request = $http({
    method: "get",
    url: "xxxxxx.php"
})
.success(function (gl) {
    $scope.users = gl;

    //initialize your chartData here or 
    //if you have already defined chartData then just push the new object
    $scope.chartData = [['Coo', $scope.users], ];
});

// Initial  data

//this will not work because request is a promise object
/*var e = request.users;
$scope.chartData = [
        ['Coo', e],
];*/
```